# Getting partial Item Count of Sharepoint list 2010

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, count, aggregation-framework

I am new to Sharepoint and Javascript

I was was wondering if there is a way to get count of items in a huge list, grouped by categories.

So i have this big list of records, made of 6 fields/categories, and one of them is called 'Component'. I was wonder if there is a way for me to get the sum of the count, grouped by components.

Or if you don't have a solution, in which direction should I head?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is [SP.List.get_itemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee548354(v=office.14)) to get items count by SharePoint JavaScript API.

Below thread shared a demo to get items count by JavaScript API with query.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/posts/getting-count-of-list-items-based-on-a-specific-condition-using-javascript-in-sharepoint-2013

More about SharePoint caml query.

http://www.sharepointcafe.net/2015/06/caml-query-in-sharepoint.html